# jQCloud not generating any elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I just added jQCloud2 library in my project using bower with below command

```
bower install jqcloud2 --save
```

jQCloud - http://mistic100.github.io/jQCloud/demo.html

Added its css and javascript file in the head

Below is the small snippet of code I am using

```
<div id="cloud">
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
  var words = [
  {text: "Lorem", weight: 13},
  {text: "Ipsum", weight: 10.5},
  {text: "Dolor", weight: 9.4},
  {text: "Sit", weight: 8},
  {text: "Amet", weight: 6.2},
  {text: "Consectetur", weight: 5},
  {text: "Adipiscing", weight: 5}
];

$('#cloud').jQCloud(words);
});
</script>
```

Libraries I am using

1. jQuery - 1.11.3
2. jQuery-UI - 1.11.3
3. Bootstrap - 3.3.5
4. jQCloud2 - 2.0.1

I don't see any code getting generated via jQCloud library, is it something wrong I have been doing. Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var words = [{
    text: "Lorem",
    weight: 13
  }, {
    text: "Ipsum",
    weight: 10.5
  }, {
    text: "Dolor",
    weight: 9.4
  }, {
    text: "Sit",
    weight: 8
  }, {
    text: "Amet",
    weight: 6.2
  }, {
    text: "Consectetur",
    weight: 5
  }, {
    text: "Adipiscing",
    weight: 5
  }];

  var some_words_with_same_weight =
    $("#jqcloud").jQCloud(words, {
      width: 500,
      height: 350
    });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>
  /*!
 * jQCloud 2.0.1
 * Copyright 2011 Luca Ongaro (http://www.lucaongaro.eu)
 * Copyright 2013 Daniel White (http://www.developerdan.com)
 * Copyright 2014 Damien "Mistic" Sorel (http://www.strangeplanet.fr)
 * Licensed under MIT (http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)
 */
!function(a){"use strict";function b(a,b,c){var d={pid:null,last:0};return function(){function e(){return d.last=(new Date).getTime(),a.apply(c||h,Array.prototype.slice.call(g))}var f=(new Date).getTime()-d.last,g=arguments,h=this;return f>b?e():(clearTimeout(d.pid),void(d.pid=setTimeout(e,b-f)))}}var c=function(b,c,d){this.$element=a(b),this.word_array=c||[],this.options=d,this.sizeGenerator=null,this.colorGenerator=null,this.data={placed_words:[],timeouts:{},namespace:null,step:null,angle:null,aspect_ratio:null,max_weight:null,min_weight:null,sizes:[],colors:[]},this.initialize()};c.DEFAULTS={width:100,height:100,center:{x:.5,y:.5},steps:10,delay:null,shape:"elliptic",classPattern:"w{n}",encodeURI:!0,removeOverflowing:!0,afterCloudRender:null,autoResize:!1,colors:null,fontSize:null},c.prototype={initialize:function(){if(this.options.width?this.$element.width(this.options.width):this.options.width=this.$element.width(),this.options.height?this.$element.height(this.options.height):this.options.height=this.$element.height(),this.options=a.extend(!0,{},c.DEFAULTS,this.options),null===this.options.delay&&(this.options.delay=this.word_array.length>50?10:0),this.options.center.x>1&&(this.options.center.x=this.options.center.x/this.options.width,this.options.center.y=this.options.center.y/this.options.height),"function"==typeof this.options.colors)this.colorGenerator=this.options.colors;else if(a.isArray(this.options.colors)){var d=this.options.colors.length;if(d>0){if(d<this.options.steps)for(var e=d;e<this.options.steps;e++)this.options.colors[e]=this.options.colors[d-1];this.colorGenerator=function(a){return this.options.colors[this.options.steps-a]}}}if("function"==typeof this.options.fontSize)this.sizeGenerator=this.options.fontSize;else if(a.isPlainObject(this.options.fontSize))this.sizeGenerator=function(a,b,c){var d=a*this.options.fontSize.from,e=a*this.options.fontSize.to;return Math.round(e+1*(d-e)/(this.options.steps-1)*(c-1))+"px"};else if(a.isArray(this.options.fontSize)){var f=this.options.fontSize.length;if(f>0){if(f<this.options.steps)for(var g=f;g<this.options.steps;g++)this.options.fontSize[g]=this.options.fontSize[f-1];this.sizeGenerator=function(a,b,c){return this.options.fontSize[this.options.steps-c]}}}this.data.angle=6.28*Math.random(),this.data.step="rectangular"===this.options.shape?18:2,this.data.aspect_ratio=this.options.width/this.options.height,this.clearTimeouts(),this.data.namespace=(this.$element.attr("id")||Math.floor(1e6*Math.random()).toString(36))+"_word_",this.$element.addClass("jqcloud"),"static"===this.$element.css("position")&&this.$element.css("position","relative"),this.createTimeout(a.proxy(this.drawWordCloud,this),10),this.options.autoResize&&a(window).on("resize",b(function(){var a={width:this.$element.width(),height:this.$element.height()};(a.width!=this.options.width||a.height!=this.options.height)&&(this.options.width=a.width,this.options.height=a.height,this.data.aspect_ratio=this.options.width/this.options.height,this.update(this.word_array))},50,this))},createTimeout:function(b,c){var d=setTimeout(a.proxy(function(){delete this.data.timeouts[d],b()},this),c);this.data.timeouts[d]=!0},clearTimeouts:function(){a.each(this.data.timeouts,function(a){clearTimeout(a)}),this.data.timeouts={}},overlapping:function(a,b){return Math.abs(2*a.left+a.width-2*b.left-b.width)<a.width+b.width&&Math.abs(2*a.top+a.height-2*b.top-b.height)<a.height+b.height?!0:!1},hitTest:function(a){for(var b=0,c=this.data.placed_words.length;c>b;b++)if(this.overlapping(a,this.data.placed_words[b]))return!0;return!1},drawWordCloud:function(){var a,b;if(this.$element.children('[id^="'+this.data.namespace+'"]').remove(),0!==this.word_array.length){for(a=0,b=this.word_array.length;b>a;a++)this.word_array[a].weight=parseFloat(this.word_array[a].weight,10);if(this.word_array.sort(function(a,b){return b.weight-a.weight}),this.data.max_weight=this.word_array[0].weight,this.data.min_weight=this.word_array[this.word_array.length-1].weight,this.data.colors=[],this.colorGenerator)for(a=0;a<this.options.steps;a++)this.data.colors.push(this.colorGenerator(a+1));if(this.data.sizes=[],this.sizeGenerator)for(a=0;a<this.options.steps;a++)this.data.sizes.push(this.sizeGenerator(this.options.width,this.options.height,a+1));if(this.options.delay>0)this.drawOneWordDelayed();else{for(a=0,b=this.word_array.length;b>a;a++)this.drawOneWord(a,this.word_array[a]);"function"==typeof this.options.afterCloudRender&&this.options.afterCloudRender.call(this.$element)}}},drawOneWord:function(b,c){var d,e,f,g=this.data.namespace+b,h=this.data.angle,i=0,j=0,k=0,l=Math.floor(this.options.steps/2);for(c.attr=a.extend({},c.html,{id:g}),this.data.max_weight!=this.data.min_weight&&(l=Math.round(1*(c.weight-this.data.min_weight)*(this.options.steps-1)/(this.data.max_weight-this.data.min_weight))+1),d=a("<span>").attr(c.attr),this.options.classPattern&&d.addClass(this.options.classPattern.replace("{n}",l)),this.data.colors.length&&d.css("color",this.data.colors[l-1]),this.data.sizes.length&&d.css("font-size",this.data.sizes[l-1]),c.link?("string"==typeof c.link&&(c.link={href:c.link}),this.options.encodeURI&&(c.link.href=encodeURI(c.link.href).replace(/'/g,"%27")),d.append(a("<a>").attr(c.link).text(c.text))):d.text(c.text),c.handlers&&d.on(c.handlers),this.$element.append(d),e={width:d.width(),height:d.height()},e.left=this.options.center.x*this.options.width-e.width/2,e.top=this.options.center.y*this.options.height-e.height/2,f=d[0].style,f.position="absolute",f.left=e.left+"px",f.top=e.top+"px";this.hitTest(e);){if("rectangular"===this.options.shape)switch(j++,j*this.data.step>(1+Math.floor(k/2))*this.data.step*(k%4%2===0?1:this.data.aspect_ratio)&&(j=0,k++),k%4){case 1:e.left+=this.data.step*this.data.aspect_ratio+2*Math.random();break;case 2:e.top-=this.data.step+2*Math.random();break;case 3:e.left-=this.data.step*this.data.aspect_ratio+2*Math.random();break;case 0:e.top+=this.data.step+2*Math.random()}else i+=this.data.step,h+=(b%2===0?1:-1)*this.data.step,e.left=this.options.center.x*this.options.width-e.width/2+i*Math.cos(h)*this.data.aspect_ratio,e.top=this.options.center.y*this.options.height+i*Math.sin(h)-e.height/2;f.left=e.left+"px",f.top=e.top+"px"}return this.options.removeOverflowing&&(e.left<0||e.top<0||e.left+e.width>this.options.width||e.top+e.height>this.options.height)?void d.remove():(this.data.placed_words.push(e),void("function"==typeof c.afterWordRender&&c.afterWordRender.call(d)))},drawOneWordDelayed:function(b){return b=b||0,this.$element.is(":visible")?void(b<this.word_array.length?(this.drawOneWord(b,this.word_array[b]),this.createTimeout(a.proxy(function(){this.drawOneWordDelayed(b+1)},this),this.options.delay)):"function"==typeof this.options.afterCloudRender&&this.options.afterCloudRender.call(this.$element)):void this.createTimeout(a.proxy(function(){this.drawOneWordDelayed(b)},this),10)},destroy:function(){this.clearTimeouts(),this.$element.removeClass("jqcloud"),this.$element.removeData("jqcloud"),this.$element.children('[id^="'+this.namespace+'"]').remove()},update:function(a){this.word_array=a,this.data.placed_words=[],this.clearTimeouts(),this.drawWordCloud()}},a.fn.jQCloud=function(b,d){var e=arguments;return this.each(function(){var f=a(this),g=f.data("jqcloud");if(g||"destroy"!==b)if(g)"string"==typeof b&&g[b].apply(g,Array.prototype.slice.call(e,1));else{var h="object"==typeof d?d:{};f.data("jqcloud",g=new c(this,b,h))}})},a.fn.jQCloud.defaults={set:function(b){a.extend(!0,c.DEFAULTS,b)},get:function(b){var d=c.DEFAULTS;return b&&(d=d[b]),a.extend(!0,{},d)}}}(jQuery);
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqcloud/1.0.4/jqcloud.css"

Copy

</head>

  
<body>

  <div id="jqcloud" class="jqcloud"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

You just needed width and height.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. width and height is explicity required

Comment: However the official document doesn't call any attention to that. Instead it says "Default configuration, no special parameters for words". So bad!