# Why am I getting "jQCloud is not a function" error?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, word-cloud

I am trying to use the jQCloud plugin. I have installed it using bower, AND included the jQCloud javascript and css files in my HTML  tags, but when I try to implement a simple example per [the docs](https://mistic100.github.io/jQCloud/), I consistently get an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jQCloud is not a function`. In addition, the css file throws a 404 Not Found error.

I read the other threads on this topic, which included answers saying that the jQCloud script must be placed *after* the jQuery script, as jQCloud is dependent on jQuery library. I've done that, and it didn't solve my issue.

I found one thread that used a different script file for the install than what's provided in the docs -- and that worked! But it's very ugly, and I don't understand why the script file in the docs wouldn't work. Plus, it doesn't solve the issue of the css file not working. You can check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804718/jqcloud-not-generating-any-elements) -- it's in the first/accepted answer.

Does anyone see issues in my code? Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-worker-rd0ggj?file=/src/test.js).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- jQuery Cloud Script File per the docs-->
   <script src="bower_components/jqcloud2/dist/jqcloud.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Script -->
    <script type="module" src="./test.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="word-cloud"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
  var words = [
    {
      text: "Lorem",
      weight: 13,
    },
    {
      text: "Ipsum",
      weight: 10.5,
    },
    {
      text: "Dolor",
      weight: 9.4,
    },
    {
      text: "Sit",
      weight: 8,
    },
    {
      text: "Amet",
      weight: 6.2,
    },
    {
      text: "Consectetur",
      weight: 5,
    },
    {
      text: "Adipiscing",
      weight: 5,
    },
  ];

  let some_words = $("#word-cloud").jQCloud(words, {
    width: 500,
    height: 350,
  });
});
```

Alternative script tag that works for me in VS Code, but not in CodeSandbox. I got it from the S/O post that I linked above - it is not in the docs and I would rather not use it if possible:

```
 <script>
  /*!
 * jQCloud 2.0.1
 * Copyright 2011 Luca Ongaro (http://www.lucaongaro.eu)
 * Copyright 2013 Daniel White (http://www.developerdan.com)
 * Copyright 2014 Damien "Mistic" Sorel (http://www.strangeplanet.fr)
 * Licensed under MIT (http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)
 */
!function(a){"use strict";function b(a,b,c){var d={pid:null,last:0};return function(){function e(){return d.last=(new Date).getTime(),a.apply(c||h,Array.prototype.slice.call(g))}var f=(new Date).getTime()-d.last,g=arguments,h=this;return f>b?e():(clearTimeout(d.pid),void(d.pid=setTimeout(e,b-f)))}}var c=function(b,c,d){this.$element=a(b),this.word_array=c||[],this.options=d,this.sizeGenerator=null,this.colorGenerator=null,this.data={placed_words:[],timeouts:{},namespace:null,step:null,angle:null,aspect_ratio:null,max_weight:null,min_weight:null,sizes:[],colors:[]},this.initialize()};c.DEFAULTS={width:100,height:100,center:{x:.5,y:.5},steps:10,delay:null,shape:"elliptic",classPattern:"w{n}",encodeURI:!0,removeOverflowing:!0,afterCloudRender:null,autoResize:!1,colors:null,fontSize:null},c.prototype={initialize:function(){if(this.options.width?this.$element.width(this.options.width):this.options.width=this.$element.width(),this.options.height?this.$element.height(this.options.height):this.options.height=this.$element.height(),this.options=a.extend(!0,{},c.DEFAULTS,this.options),null===this.options.delay&&(this.options.delay=this.word_array.length>50?10:0),this.options.center.x>1&&(this.options.center.x=this.options.center.x/this.options.width,this.options.center.y=this.options.center.y/this.options.height),"function"==typeof this.options.colors)this.colorGenerator=this.options.colors;else if(a.isArray(this.options.colors)){var d=this.options.colors.length;if(d>0){if(d<this.options.steps)for(var e=d;e<this.options.steps;e++)this.options.colors[e]=this.options.colors[d-1];this.colorGenerator=function(a){return this.options.colors[this.options.steps-a]}}}if("function"==typeof this.options.fontSize)this.sizeGenerator=this.options.fontSize;else if(a.isPlainObject(this.options.fontSize))this.sizeGenerator=function(a,b,c){var d=a*this.options.fontSize.from,e=a*this.options.fontSize.to;return Math.round(e+1*(d-e)/(this.options.steps-1)*(c-1))+"px"};else if(a.isArray(this.options.fontSize)){var f=this.options.fontSize.length;if(f>0){if(f<this.options.steps)for(var g=f;g<this.options.steps;g++)this.options.fontSize[g]=this.options.fontSize[f-1];this.sizeGenerator=function(a,b,c){return this.options.fontSize[this.options.steps-c]}}}this.data.angle=6.28*Math.random(),this.data.step="rectangular"===this.options.shape?18:2,this.data.aspect_ratio=this.options.width/this.options.height,this.clearTimeouts(),this.data.namespace=(this.$element.attr("id")||Math.floor(1e6*Math.random()).toString(36))+"_word_",this.$element.addClass("jqcloud"),"static"===this.$element.css("position")&&this.$element.css("position","relative"),this.createTimeout(a.proxy(this.drawWordCloud,this),10),this.options.autoResize&&a(window).on("resize",b(function(){var a={width:this.$element.width(),height:this.$element.height()};(a.width!=this.options.width||a.height!=this.options.height)&&(this.options.width=a.width,this.options.height=a.height,this.data.aspect_ratio=this.options.width/this.options.height,this.update(this.word_array))},50,this))},createTimeout:function(b,c){var d=setTimeout(a.proxy(function(){delete this.data.timeouts[d],b()},this),c);this.data.timeouts[d]=!0},clearTimeouts:function(){a.each(this.data.timeouts,function(a){clearTimeout(a)}),this.data.timeouts={}},overlapping:function(a,b){return Math.abs(2*a.left+a.width-2*b.left-b.width)<a.width+b.width&&Math.abs(2*a.top+a.height-2*b.top-b.height)<a.height+b.height?!0:!1},hitTest:function(a){for(var b=0,c=this.data.placed_words.length;c>b;b++)if(this.overlapping(a,this.data.placed_words[b]))return!0;return!1},drawWordCloud:function(){var a,b;if(this.$element.children('[id^="'+this.data.namespace+'"]').remove(),0!==this.word_array.length){for(a=0,b=this.word_array.length;b>a;a++)this.word_array[a].weight=parseFloat(this.word_array[a].weight,10);if(this.word_array.sort(function(a,b){return b.weight-a.weight}),this.data.max_weight=this.word_array[0].weight,this.data.min_weight=this.word_array[this.word_array.length-1].weight,this.data.colors=[],this.colorGenerator)for(a=0;a<this.options.steps;a++)this.data.colors.push(this.colorGenerator(a+1));if(this.data.sizes=[],this.sizeGenerator)for(a=0;a<this.options.steps;a++)this.data.sizes.push(this.sizeGenerator(this.options.width,this.options.height,a+1));if(this.options.delay>0)this.drawOneWordDelayed();else{for(a=0,b=this.word_array.length;b>a;a++)this.drawOneWord(a,this.word_array[a]);"function"==typeof this.options.afterCloudRender&&this.options.afterCloudRender.call(this.$element)}}},drawOneWord:function(b,c){var d,e,f,g=this.data.namespace+b,h=this.data.angle,i=0,j=0,k=0,l=Math.floor(this.options.steps/2);for(c.attr=a.extend({},c.html,{id:g}),this.data.max_weight!=this.data.min_weight&&(l=Math.round(1*(c.weight-this.data.min_weight)*(this.options.steps-1)/(this.data.max_weight-this.data.min_weight))+1),d=a("<span>").attr(c.attr),this.options.classPattern&&d.addClass(this.options.classPattern.replace("{n}",l)),this.data.colors.length&&d.css("color",this.data.colors[l-1]),this.data.sizes.length&&d.css("font-size",this.data.sizes[l-1]),c.link?("string"==typeof c.link&&(c.link={href:c.link}),this.options.encodeURI&&(c.link.href=encodeURI(c.link.href).replace(/'/g,"%27")),d.append(a("<a>").attr(c.link).text(c.text))):d.text(c.text),c.handlers&&d.on(c.handlers),this.$element.append(d),e={width:d.width(),height:d.height()},e.left=this.options.center.x*this.options.width-e.width/2,e.top=this.options.center.y*this.options.height-e.height/2,f=d[0].style,f.position="absolute",f.left=e.left+"px",f.top=e.top+"px";this.hitTest(e);){if("rectangular"===this.options.shape)switch(j++,j*this.data.step>(1+Math.floor(k/2))*this.data.step*(k%4%2===0?1:this.data.aspect_ratio)&&(j=0,k++),k%4){case 1:e.left+=this.data.step*this.data.aspect_ratio+2*Math.random();break;case 2:e.top-=this.data.step+2*Math.random();break;case 3:e.left-=this.data.step*this.data.aspect_ratio+2*Math.random();break;case 0:e.top+=this.data.step+2*Math.random()}else i+=this.data.step,h+=(b%2===0?1:-1)*this.data.step,e.left=this.options.center.x*this.options.width-e.width/2+i*Math.cos(h)*this.data.aspect_ratio,e.top=this.options.center.y*this.options.height+i*Math.sin(h)-e.height/2;f.left=e.left+"px",f.top=e.top+"px"}return this.options.removeOverflowing&&(e.left<0||e.top<0||e.left+e.width>this.options.width||e.top+e.height>this.options.height)?void d.remove():(this.data.placed_words.push(e),void("function"==typeof c.afterWordRender&&c.afterWordRender.call(d)))},drawOneWordDelayed:function(b){return b=b||0,this.$element.is(":visible")?void(b<this.word_array.length?(this.drawOneWord(b,this.word_array[b]),this.createTimeout(a.proxy(function(){this.drawOneWordDelayed(b+1)},this),this.options.delay)):"function"==typeof this.options.afterCloudRender&&this.options.afterCloudRender.call(this.$element)):void this.createTimeout(a.proxy(function(){this.drawOneWordDelayed(b)},this),10)},destroy:function(){this.clearTimeouts(),this.$element.removeClass("jqcloud"),this.$element.removeData("jqcloud"),this.$element.children('[id^="'+this.namespace+'"]').remove()},update:function(a){this.word_array=a,this.data.placed_words=[],this.clearTimeouts(),this.drawWordCloud()}},a.fn.jQCloud=function(b,d){var e=arguments;return this.each(function(){var f=a(this),g=f.data("jqcloud");if(g||"destroy"!==b)if(g)"string"==typeof b&&g[b].apply(g,Array.prototype.slice.call(e,1));else{var h="object"==typeof d?d:{};f.data("jqcloud",g=new c(this,b,h))}})},a.fn.jQCloud.defaults={set:function(b){a.extend(!0,c.DEFAULTS,b)},get:function(b){var d=c.DEFAULTS;return b&&(d=d[b]),a.extend(!0,{},d)}}}(jQuery);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine had a project with jQCloud working, which I used for reference. They downloaded the source .js and .css files and then referenced them locally. This worked for me.

I added the following files to my project and then linked them to the pages that needed to use jQCloud:

jqcloud.min.js

```
/*!
 * jQCloud 2.0.3
 * Copyright 2011 Luca Ongaro (http://www.lucaongaro.eu)
 * Copyright 2013 Daniel White (http://www.developerdan.com)
 * Copyright 2014-2017 Damien "Mistic" Sorel (http://www.strangeplanet.fr)
 * Licensed under MIT (http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)
 */
!(function (a, b) {
  "function" == typeof define && define.amd
    ? define(["jquery"], b)
    : "object" == typeof module && module.exports
    ? (module.exports = b(require("jquery")))
    : b(a.jQuery);
})(this, function (a) {
  "use strict";
  function b(a, b, c) {
    var d = { pid: null, last: 0 };
    return function () {
      function e() {
        return (
          (d.last = new Date().getTime()),
          a.apply(c || h, Array.prototype.slice.call(g))
        );
      }
      var f = new Date().getTime() - d.last,
        g = arguments,
        h = this;
      return f > b
        ? e()
        : (clearTimeout(d.pid), void (d.pid = setTimeout(e, b - f)));
    };
  }
  var c = function (b, c, d) {
    (this.$element = a(b)),
      (this.word_array = c || []),
      (this.options = d),
      (this.sizeGenerator = null),
      (this.colorGenerator = null),
      (this.data = {
        placed_words: [],
        timeouts: {},
        namespace: null,
        step: null,
        angle: null,
        aspect_ratio: null,
        max_weight: null,
        min_weight: null,
        sizes: [],
        colors: [],
      }),
      this.initialize();
  };
  (c.DEFAULTS = {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    center: { x: 0.5, y: 0.5 },
    steps: 10,
    delay: null,
    shape: "elliptic",
    classPattern: "w{n}",
    encodeURI: !0,
    removeOverflowing: !0,
    afterCloudRender: null,
    autoResize: !1,
    colors: null,
    fontSize: null,
    template: null,
  }),
    (c.prototype = {
      initialize: function () {
        if (
          (this.options.width
            ? this.$element.width(this.options.width)
            : (this.options.width = this.$element.width()),
          this.options.height
            ? this.$element.height(this.options.height)
            : (this.options.height = this.$element.height()),
          (this.options = a.extend(!0, {}, c.DEFAULTS, this.options)),
          null === this.options.delay &&
            (this.options.delay = this.word_array.length > 50 ? 10 : 0),
          this.options.center.x > 1 &&
            ((this.options.center.x =
              this.options.center.x / this.options.width),
            (this.options.center.y =
              this.options.center.y / this.options.height)),
          "function" == typeof this.options.colors)
        )
          this.colorGenerator = this.options.colors;
        else if (a.isArray(this.options.colors)) {
          var d = this.options.colors.length;
          if (d > 0) {
            if (d < this.options.steps)
              for (var e = d; e < this.options.steps; e++)
                this.options.colors[e] = this.options.colors[d - 1];
            this.colorGenerator = function (a) {
              return this.options.colors[this.options.steps - a];
            };
          }
        }
        if ("function" == typeof this.options.fontSize)
          this.sizeGenerator = this.options.fontSize;
        else if (a.isPlainObject(this.options.fontSize))
          this.sizeGenerator = function (a, b, c) {
            var d = a * this.options.fontSize.from,
              e = a * this.options.fontSize.to;
            return (
              Math.round(
                e + ((1 * (d - e)) / (this.options.steps - 1)) * (c - 1)
              ) + "px"
            );
          };
        else if (a.isArray(this.options.fontSize)) {
          var f = this.options.fontSize.length;
          if (f > 0) {
            if (f < this.options.steps)
              for (var g = f; g < this.options.steps; g++)
                this.options.fontSize[g] = this.options.fontSize[f - 1];
            this.sizeGenerator = function (a, b, c) {
              return this.options.fontSize[this.options.steps - c];
            };
          }
        }
        (this.data.angle = 6.28 * Math.random()),
          (this.data.step = "rectangular" === this.options.shape ? 18 : 2),
          (this.data.aspect_ratio = this.options.width / this.options.height),
          this.clearTimeouts(),
          (this.data.namespace =
            (this.$element.attr("id") ||
              Math.floor(1e6 * Math.random()).toString(36)) + "_word_"),
          this.$element.addClass("jqcloud"),
          "static" === this.$element.css("position") &&
            this.$element.css("position", "relative"),
          this.createTimeout(a.proxy(this.drawWordCloud, this), 10),
          this.options.autoResize &&
            a(window).on(
              "resize." + this.data.namespace,
              b(this.resize, 50, this)
            );
      },
      createTimeout: function (b, c) {
        var d = setTimeout(
          a.proxy(function () {
            delete this.data.timeouts[d], b();
          }, this),
          c
        );
        this.data.timeouts[d] = !0;
      },
      clearTimeouts: function () {
        a.each(this.data.timeouts, function (a) {
          clearTimeout(a);
        }),
          (this.data.timeouts = {});
      },
      overlapping: function (a, b) {
        return (
          Math.abs(2 * a.left + a.width - 2 * b.left - b.width) <
            a.width + b.width &&
          Math.abs(2 * a.top + a.height - 2 * b.top - b.height) <
            a.height + b.height
        );
      },
      hitTest: function (a) {
        for (var b = 0, c = this.data.placed_words.length; b < c; b++)
          if (this.overlapping(a, this.data.placed_words[b])) return !0;
        return !1;
      },
      drawWordCloud: function () {
        var a, b;
        if (
          (this.$element
            .children('[id^="' + this.data.namespace + '"]')
            .remove(),
          0 !== this.word_array.length)
        ) {
          for (a = 0, b = this.word_array.length; a < b; a++)
            this.word_array[a].weight = parseFloat(
              this.word_array[a].weight,
              10
            );
          if (
            (this.word_array.sort(function (a, b) {
              return b.weight - a.weight;
            }),
            (this.data.max_weight = this.word_array[0].weight),
            (this.data.min_weight =
              this.word_array[this.word_array.length - 1].weight),
            (this.data.colors = []),
            this.colorGenerator)
          )
            for (a = 0; a < this.options.steps; a++)
              this.data.colors.push(this.colorGenerator(a + 1));
          if (((this.data.sizes = []), this.sizeGenerator))
            for (a = 0; a < this.options.steps; a++)
              this.data.sizes.push(
                this.sizeGenerator(
                  this.options.width,
                  this.options.height,
                  a + 1
                )
              );
          if (this.options.delay > 0) this.drawOneWordDelayed();
          else {
            for (a = 0, b = this.word_array.length; a < b; a++)
              this.drawOneWord(a, this.word_array[a]);
            "function" == typeof this.options.afterCloudRender &&
              this.options.afterCloudRender.call(this.$element);
          }
        }
      },
      drawOneWord: function (b, c) {
        var d,
          e,
          f,
          g = this.data.namespace + b,
          h = this.data.angle,
          i = 0,
          j = 0,
          k = 0,
          l = Math.floor(this.options.steps / 2);
        for (
          c.attr = a.extend({}, c.html, { id: g }),
            this.data.max_weight != this.data.min_weight &&
              (l =
                Math.round(
                  (1 *
                    (c.weight - this.data.min_weight) *
                    (this.options.steps - 1)) /
                    (this.data.max_weight - this.data.min_weight)
                ) + 1),
            d = a("<span>").attr(c.attr),
            d.addClass("jqcloud-word"),
            this.options.classPattern &&
              d.addClass(this.options.classPattern.replace("{n}", l)),
            this.data.colors.length && d.css("color", this.data.colors[l - 1]),
            c.color && d.css("color", c.color),
            this.data.sizes.length &&
              d.css("font-size", this.data.sizes[l - 1]),
            this.options.template
              ? d.html(this.options.template(c))
              : c.link
              ? ("string" == typeof c.link && (c.link = { href: c.link }),
                this.options.encodeURI &&
                  (c.link.href = encodeURI(c.link.href).replace(/'/g, "%27")),
                d.append(a("<a>").attr(c.link).text(c.text)))
              : d.text(c.text),
            c.handlers && d.on(c.handlers),
            this.$element.append(d),
            e = { width: d.outerWidth(), height: d.outerHeight() },
            e.left = this.options.center.x * this.options.width - e.width / 2,
            e.top = this.options.center.y * this.options.height - e.height / 2,
            f = d[0].style,
            f.position = "absolute",
            f.left = e.left + "px",
            f.top = e.top + "px";
          this.hitTest(e);

        ) {
          if ("rectangular" === this.options.shape)
            switch (
              (j++,
              j * this.data.step >
                (1 + Math.floor(k / 2)) *
                  this.data.step *
                  ((k % 4) % 2 === 0 ? 1 : this.data.aspect_ratio) &&
                ((j = 0), k++),
              k % 4)
            ) {
              case 1:
                e.left +=
                  this.data.step * this.data.aspect_ratio + 2 * Math.random();
                break;
              case 2:
                e.top -= this.data.step + 2 * Math.random();
                break;
              case 3:
                e.left -=
                  this.data.step * this.data.aspect_ratio + 2 * Math.random();
                break;
              case 0:
                e.top += this.data.step + 2 * Math.random();
            }
          else
            (i += this.data.step),
              (h += (b % 2 === 0 ? 1 : -1) * this.data.step),
              (e.left =
                this.options.center.x * this.options.width -
                e.width / 2 +
                i * Math.cos(h) * this.data.aspect_ratio),
              (e.top =
                this.options.center.y * this.options.height +
                i * Math.sin(h) -
                e.height / 2);
          (f.left = e.left + "px"), (f.top = e.top + "px");
        }
        return this.options.removeOverflowing &&
          (e.left < 0 ||
            e.top < 0 ||
            e.left + e.width > this.options.width ||
            e.top + e.height > this.options.height)
          ? void d.remove()
          : (this.data.placed_words.push(e),
            void (
              "function" == typeof c.afterWordRender &&
              c.afterWordRender.call(d)
            ));
      },
      drawOneWordDelayed: function (b) {
        return (
          (b = b || 0),
          this.$element.is(":visible")
            ? void (b < this.word_array.length
                ? (this.drawOneWord(b, this.word_array[b]),
                  this.createTimeout(
                    a.proxy(function () {
                      this.drawOneWordDelayed(b + 1);
                    }, this),
                    this.options.delay
                  ))
                : "function" == typeof this.options.afterCloudRender &&
                  this.options.afterCloudRender.call(this.$element))
            : void this.createTimeout(
                a.proxy(function () {
                  this.drawOneWordDelayed(b);
                }, this),
                10
              )
        );
      },
      destroy: function () {
        this.options.autoResize &&
          a(window).off("resize." + this.data.namespace),
          this.clearTimeouts(),
          this.$element.removeClass("jqcloud"),
          this.$element.removeData("jqcloud"),
          this.$element
            .children('[id^="' + this.data.namespace + '"]')
            .remove();
      },
      update: function (a) {
        (this.word_array = a),
          (this.data.placed_words = []),
          this.clearTimeouts(),
          this.drawWordCloud();
      },
      resize: function () {
        var a = {
          width: this.$element.width(),
          height: this.$element.height(),
        };
        (a.width == this.options.width && a.height == this.options.height) ||
          ((this.options.width = a.width),
          (this.options.height = a.height),
          (this.data.aspect_ratio = this.options.width / this.options.height),
          this.update(this.word_array));
      },
    }),
    (a.fn.jQCloud = function (b, d) {
      var e = arguments;
      return this.each(function () {
        var f = a(this),
          g = f.data("jqcloud");
        if (g || "destroy" !== b)
          if (g)
            "string" == typeof b &&
              g[b].apply(g, Array.prototype.slice.call(e, 1));
          else {
            var h = "object" == typeof d ? d : {};
            f.data("jqcloud", (g = new c(this, b, h)));
          }
      });
    }),
    (a.fn.jQCloud.defaults = {
      set: function (b) {
        a.extend(!0, c.DEFAULTS, b);
      },
      get: function (b) {
        var d = c.DEFAULTS;
        return b && (d = d[b]), a.extend(!0, {}, d);
      },
    });
});
```

jqcloud.css

```
/*!
 * jQCloud 2.0.3
 * Copyright 2011 Luca Ongaro (http://www.lucaongaro.eu)
 * Copyright 2013 Daniel White (http://www.developerdan.com)
 * Copyright 2014-2017 Damien "Mistic" Sorel (http://www.strangeplanet.fr)
 * Licensed under MIT (http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)
 */
.jqcloud {
  font: 8px "Lintel", "Arial", sans-serif;
  line-height: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.jqcloud-word {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.jqcloud-word.w1 {
  color: #4961eb;
  font-size: 100%;
}
.jqcloud-word.w2 {
  color: #6293b4;
  font-size: 150%;
}
.jqcloud-word.w3 {
  color: #74a1b8;
  font-size: 200%;
}
.jqcloud-word.w4 {
  color: #1762a0;
  font-size: 250%;
}
.jqcloud-word.w5 {
  color: #90a0dd;
  font-size: 300%;
}
.jqcloud-word.w6 {
  color: #90c5f0;
  font-size: 350%;
}
.jqcloud-word.w7 {
  color: #3399dd;
  font-size: 400%;
}
.jqcloud-word.w8 {
  color: #00ccff;
  font-size: 450%;
}
.jqcloud-word.w9 {
  color: #00ccff;
  font-size: 500%;
}
.jqcloud-word.w10 {
  color: #00ccff;
  font-size: 550%;
}
.jqcloud-word a {
  color: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.jqcloud-word a:hover {
  color: #00ccff;
}
```

Then, in HTML files that need to use jQCloud:

```
<script src="../jqcloud.min.js"></script>
<link href="../jqcloud.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```